# PowerShell Parallel vs Sequential Jobs - Sequential is faster?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to implement multithreaded parsing of Windows EventLogs and on a dual core system I'm finding that the sequential code is far faster than the parallel code. These are the examples:

**Sequential:**

```
$start = Get-Date

$code1 = { Get-WinEvent -Path "D:\logs\hostname-security-20131003005914.evtx" -MaxEvents 200 }
$code2 = { Get-WinEvent -Path "D:\logs\hostname-security-20131003015906.evtx" -MaxEvents 200 }

$result1 = & $code1
$result2 = & $code2

$end = Get-Date
$timespan = $end - $start
$seconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
Write-Host "This took me $seconds seconds in all."
```

**Parallel:**

```
$start = Get-Date

$code1 = { Get-WinEvent -Path "D:\logs\hostname-security-20131003005914.evtx" -MaxEvents 200 }
$code2 = { Get-WinEvent -Path "D:\logs\hostname-security-20131003015906.evtx" -MaxEvents 200 }

$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code1 
$job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code2 

$alljobs = Wait-Job $job1, $job2
$result1, $result2 = Receive-Job $alljobs

$end = Get-Date
$timespan = $end - $start

$seconds = $timespan.TotalSeconds
Write-Host "This took me $seconds seconds in all."
```

The sequential code runs in ~5 seconds (with close to 50% CPU usage) whereas the parallel code runs in ~19 seconds (with close to 100% CPU usage). I have echo'd the results to make sure they are both correct and that seems fine.

I'm running Windows 8. PowerShell details are:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18051
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16628
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
It is not just Get-WinEvent that produces this conundrum; I tried with Get-ChildItem with the same results.

With this as the code to execute however, the parallel code runs quicker (as expected):

```
$code1 = { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; "A" }
$code2 = { Start-Sleep -Seconds 12; "B" }
```

17.002 seconds for sequential.
14.2 seconds for parallel.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a Powershell job, Powershell creates a new session to run the scriptblock in.

Try this:

```
measure-command { start-job -ScriptBlock {} }
```

That's how much time it costs you to create the job.  If the task you're using the job for takes less time than that, you're better off just running the tasks sequentially in your local session.

Comment: Whilst this makes sense, unfortunately it doesn't account for what I'm seeing. The time taken to create the jobs is very small. To lengthen the tasks themselves I've increased the -MaxEvents to 2000 and am now running this on my work computer (quad core i7). The time taken to create $job1 is 0.18 seconds and $job2 0.11 seconds in the parallel code. CPU usage is close to 50% (using 2 cores). It takes ~49 seconds. Sequential code runs in 18 seconds with ~25% CPU usage.

Comment: I tried running a single job in the parallel code. It also took ~49s. Adding a Get-Date | Out-File to the script block both before and after Get-WinEvent showed it was this that was taking up the time and not wait-job or receive-job. So, the behaviour of Get-WinEvent is different when running inside a scriptblock in parallel jobs vs sequential code. The same time differences are apparent on both my Windows 8.1 machine *and* Server 2008R2 (I suspected maybe the desktop OS was putting parallel processes in the background but experiencing the same results on a server eliminates that).

Comment: @Rob Do this: Add a -Keep after your Receive-Jobs then go and look at each job individually.  There's a beginTime and endTime timestamp.  That will give you a much more accurate look at what's going on with the jobs themselves, and I think you'll be surprised.  Incidentally, have you tried using a parallel block in a Powershell workflow?  Might work better for you.

Comment: @CrownedJitter: Thanks for the suggestion. Using -keep actually gave the same results as my Get-Date hack! Both jobs have exactly the same PSBeginTime and PSEndTime. It's just that they take longer for some bizarre reason. I've edited the original post to show this is not the case if you simply use Start-Sleep. As soon as the script block involves real CPU time, parallel take longer. My abilities don't currently stretch to runspaces / workflows but I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

For each job you create, a new powershell process is created which requires resources for scheduling, loading up the .net runtime, etc. It gives a lot of CPU overhead and requires 20mb+ memory minimum per job.

Because of this, jobs are more suited for:

- Long-running scripts that go on for minutes or hours.
- Running code in parrallel on multiple computers.

Comment: Thank you. I lengthened the processes but I'm still experiencing counter-intuitive results as noted on the reply to the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Further documentation supporting what's already been said here, from Thomas Lee at http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2010/12/powershell-jobs.html :

"Each time you run a PowerShell job (whether in the ISE or console), PowerShell creates an instance of PowerShell.exe to execute the script or script block. This means that each job comes with a bit of overhead – process creation has CPU/IO/Memory requirements. But if you can run multiple tasks in separate processes, then with Window’s multiprocessing features, the jobs run in parallel and therefore a much shorter overall time. At least in theory!

As ever it depends. If the task being executed uses a lot or resources to actually execute, then having multiple tasks run in parallel therefore raises the resource utilisation. Specifically, with more than one or two ‘heavy’ tasks, you can find the system is paging heavily. This paging might actually end up slowing the execution down to the point where there the benefits of parallelisation are swept away by the paging costs."

Comment: I'd love to be able to explain it away by paging but my system is not doing so (system running very little, 8GB RAM, quad core i7 on SSD). Could you try these examples that should run in memory only? Sequential: [link](http://pastebin.com/7enDSCkK) and Parallel: [link](http://pastebin.com/x1BCYNgV) - if you're unconvinced by the length the numbers can be adjusted. Save these as separate PS1 files and run in separate PS windows. When the parallel code runs the two launched PS processes consume ~46-48% CPU each on process monitor. Code takes nearly 10x longer than sequential.

Comment: If however I run this in PowerGUI, Parallel is faster.